# How to extract media folder from a lot of .PPT files with PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, powerpoint

I have a bunch of PowerPoint presentations, and I need to extract all the images out of every file. I've noticed (by opening one of those files with 7Zip) that it contains a 'Media' folder where all the images are located. is there any way to extract the 'Media' folder for every file, out to an individual folder for each file?

Comment: Can you confirm the files are ppt files as opposed to pptx?

Comment: @JamesC. Since Daniel can open them with WinRar and see the media folder, they must be .pptx rather than .ppt files.  Sometimes users (looking at myself here too) use PPT as an abbreviation for PowerPoint rather than as the file extension.

Comment: That's right, it's PPTx, all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote this *really* fast, so I wouldn't be surprised if there's a better way, or at least, a cleaner way to accomplish what you're after. It's written to work both in instances where there is, and isn't, an embedded media folder.

For testing purposes, I had a folder on my desktop called pptx with four *.pptx files inside of it. Once the quick script completed, it had created a folder for each PowerPoint file in the same folder. In each of those folders is either a media folder with the files you're after, or a text file that indicates a media folder could not be found. Again, there's probably a cleaner way, but until then, this should work.

```
$Path = 'C:\users\tommymaynard\Desktop\pptx'
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path

Foreach ($File in $Files) {
    New-Item -Path $File.DirectoryName -ItemType Directory -Name $File.BaseName | Out-Null

If (Get-Command -Name Expand-Archive) {
    Expand-Archive -Path $File.FullName -OutputPath $File.FullName.Split('.')[0]

} Else {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($File.FullName,$File.FullName.Split('.')[0])
} # End If-Else.

If (Test-Path -Path "$($File.FullName.Split('.')[0])\ppt\media") {
    Move-Item -Path "$($File.FullName.Split('.')[0])\ppt\media" -Destination $File.FullName.Split('.')[0]
    Get-ChildItem -Path $File.FullName.Split('.')[0] | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne 'media'} | Remove-Item -Recurse

} Else {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $File.FullName.Split('.')[0] | Remove-Item -Recurse
    New-Item -Path $File.FullName.Split('.')[0] -ItemType File -Name 'No media folder.txt' | Out-Null
} # End If-Else.
} # End Foreach.
```

Edit: Using .NET is *so* much faster than Expand-Archive! If speed is what you're after, and you're running a version of PowerShell that includes Expand-Archive, then change Get-Command -Name Expand-Archive to $true -eq $false to force that .NET be used. Either that, or just dump the first If-Else and pull out that .NET code... let us know if you need further assistance.

Edit2: I wrote about this post on my own blog: http://tommymaynard.com/extract-media-folder-from-powerpoint-files-2017/. It has an updated version of my code.